# Environment Variables work for build not for npm run serve --mode *env

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

I'm trying to understand why my environment variables work with `npm run build` and not `vue-cli-service serve --mode sandbox`

I've followed the vue docs here

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#using-the-binary

1. I created the .env files for the different modes I will have the app in.
2. When I do an npm run build and serve it up with node, the .env variables are correct and I can see them with the end product. However, when I do an `vue-cli-service serve --mode sandbox`
3. I feel like I'm missing something here. Is there another place it needs to be configured

The docs do a good job covering over build but I don't know what to do when it comes to serve.

```
DockerFile              node_modules            src
README.md               package-lock.json       tests
__mocks__               package.json            tsconfig.json
babel.config.js         postcss.config.js       tslint.json
dist                    public                  vue.config.js
jest.config.js          server.js
```

My .env files are actually in this folder structure as well

Here is the variable in my .env files

```
VUE_APP_WEB_API='https://whateverEnvironmentApiINeed'
```

the names of the files are below

```
.env
.env.development.local
.env.sandbox.local
.env.qa.local
.env.production.local
```

Comment: Can you show us the names of your `.env` files and their contents please? - at least the variable names.

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score -1):

It was working the whole time. Just had to restart vscode in order for it to work correctly